# OnDraw Method is not Working Correctly / as expected Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, draw, renderer

my main problem is a kind of ui-refresh behavior which destroys my custom drawing on screen in Xamarin.Forms, Platformspecific renderer for android.

I draw a rectangle with semitransparent black color. This rect is fullscreen size. It inherits a smaller rectangle with the size and cornerradius of an frame which is laying on top of the customview. 
The inner rect is drawing with Xfermode (PorterDuff.Mode) Src_Out. The Result is a fullscreen rect with an small rect inside which is completly transparent.

That works quite fine, but only at a special scenario.

When i want to draw just this customview, my ui refreshes in some way i wont expect. 
The complete view is drawn correctly but after 0.5-1 sec the ui refreshes and the small transparent rect disappears in some way.

When i have this customview inside of an stacklayout and on top of it any kind of other control, it wont refresh/dispappear after time.

I am using Xamrin.Forms 4.1 in VS 19.
The ContentPage includes a ZXingQrCodeView and some other controls to diplay text and behavior.

The type of the customview is ContentView, it has no extra bindable properties. It is used just nativ to have a "new" contentview to work with.

It is my second attempt to draw a view competly new with OnDraw, in xamarin forms i have a reletavie good knowledge, i tried to change the type of the customview to stacklayout.

Content of ContentPage

```
<ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <customviews:HeaderTextView Margin="0,0,0,0" />
            <Grid HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">


                <Label
                    Grid.Row="0"
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    Margin="40,17,40,0"
                    FontSize="Small"
                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                    Text="Scannen Sie den QR-Code Ihrer Maschine"
                    TextColor="DarkGray"
                    VerticalOptions="Start" />

                <forms:ZXingScannerView
                    Grid.Row="0"
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    AutomationId="zxingScannerView"
                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                    IsAnalyzing="{Binding isAnalyzing}"
                    IsScanning="{Binding isScanning}"
                    ScanResultCommand="{Binding resultCommand}"
                    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />


                <customcontrols:CustomContentView
                    Grid.Row="0"
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">

                    <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                        <Frame
                            x:Name="clearFrame"
                            Padding="0"
                            BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                            BorderColor="#FE6A00"
                            CornerRadius="10"
                            HeightRequest="295"
                            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                            WidthRequest="295" />
                    </StackLayout>

                </customcontrols:CustomContentView>
            </Grid>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
```

CustomRenderer Android  OnDraw

```
var element = this.Element;

            var frame = (Frame)element.Content.FindByName("clearFrame");

            int hPixel = (int)TypedValue.ApplyDimension(ComplexUnitType.Dip, (float)frame.Height, Context.Resources.DisplayMetrics);
            int wPixel = (int)TypedValue.ApplyDimension(ComplexUnitType.Dip, (float)frame.Width, Context.Resources.DisplayMetrics);

            int cPixel = (int)TypedValue.ApplyDimension(ComplexUnitType.Dip, (float)frame.CornerRadius, Context.Resources.DisplayMetrics);

            var rect = new Rect();
            this.GetDrawingRect(rect);

            var paint = new Paint()
            {
                Color = Android.Graphics.Color.Argb(115, 5, 5, 5),
                AntiAlias = true
            };

            canvas.DrawRect(new RectF(rect), paint);

            Rect innerRect = new Rect();
            this.GetDrawingRect(innerRect);

            var x = (innerRect.Right / 2) - (wPixel / 2);
            var y = (innerRect.Bottom / 2) - (hPixel / 2);
            var x2 = (innerRect.Right / 2) + (wPixel / 2);
            var y2 = (innerRect.Bottom / 2) + (hPixel / 2);

            innerRect.Bottom = y2;
            innerRect.Right = x;
            innerRect.Top = y;
            innerRect.Left = x2;


            var innerPaint = new Paint()
            {
                Color = Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent,
                AntiAlias = true
            };

            innerPaint.SetXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SrcOut));

            canvas.DrawRoundRect(new RectF(innerRect), (float)cPixel, (float)cPixel, innerPaint);
```

I expect a corretly drawn rectangle in each situation but somehow it acts quite unexpected

I hope my bad english is somehow readable, if not i will try my best to explain it better.

Greetings 
Hendrik

Comment: Can you share your solution on Github? Im not able to see any issue

Comment: Unfortunately not because of customer datasecurity reasons, but i'll set up a test solution and share it

Comment: https://github.com/hendriksandberg/XamarinFormsDrawTest

Here is my Test Project, it dont work as expected, but during the initialization i found some intresting points, i will explain tomorrow

Comment: Ok please do, would love to help you

Comment: Good Morning ;)
during the initialization i discovered a quite intresting point, it seems to be a problem with Prism.Forms.
I added Prism at last to the Project, beforehand everything seems to work perfectly.

Could it be some problems with lifecycle and refreshes of the page it self ?

Comment: Definitely could be a possibility of a problem with life cycle and refreshes. Share your findings

Comment: I'l dive deeper into it and try to keep this thread on point.
Luckily my ui needs to have another control ontop of the custom contentview. 
Atm is everything fine.

Maybe i'll push this thread also to prism repo on github.